# Best practice for starting/stopping daemons as part of a unittest (using pytest)

Tags: python, fixture, pytest

Functional testing of code often requires external resources like e.g. a database.

There are basically two approaches:

- assuming that a resource (e.g. database) is always running and is always available
- start/stop the related resource as part of the test

In the "old" world of Python unittest(2) world setUp() and tearDown() methods could
be used for controlling the services.

With py.test the world became more complicated and the concept of setUp() and tearDown() methods has been replaced with the funcarg magic for implementing fixtures.
Honestly this approach is broken - at least as a replacement for setUp/tearDown methods.

What is the recommended way for controlling services and resources in a project where py.test is used?

Should we continue writing our tests (at least where needed) with setUp/tearDown methods or is there a better pattern?

Comment: Why do you think the fixtures approach is broken? What specific problem are you having with it?

Answer (score 1):

pytest supports xUnit style setup/teardown methods, see http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html so if you prefer this style you can just use it.

Using http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html one can also instantiate a "session" scoped fixture which can instantiate external processes for the whole test run and return a connection object. Code would roughly look like this:

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def connection():
    ... instantiate process ...
    return connection_to_process_or_url
```

and test files using it like this:

```
# content of test_conn.py
def test_conn_ok(connection):
    ... work with connection ...
```

If you want to keep up the service between test runs, you will need to write some logic (storing PID, checking it's alive, if no PID or not alive, start a new process) yourself for the time being (a future release might include such support code).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this in pytest seems to be with session-scoped fixtures, as [hpk42 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299202/3231557).  You can use a `yield` statement to succinctly inline setup/teardown into a single call, as per the [Fixture finalization / executing teardown code section of the documentation](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code):

```
import smtplib
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp(request):
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
    yield smtp  # provide the fixture value
    print("teardown smtp")
    smtp.close()
```

In this case you could use session scope if you didn't want this to run per-module.